# Docker Security issue around ENTRYPOINT

Tags: security, docker, containers

I am experimenting with Docker and understanding concepts around use of volumes. I have a tomcat app which writes files to a particular volume.

I write a Dockerfile with `ENTRYPOINT` of "`dosomething.sh`"

The issue I have with entrypoint script is ..

In the "`dosomething.sh`", I could potentially have a malicious code to delete all files on the volume !!!

Is there a way to guard against it, especially because, I was planning on sharing  this dockerfile and script with my dev team too and the care i have to take for production role out appears scary !

One thought is not to have an "`ENTRYPOINT`" at all for all the containers that have volumes.
Experienced folks,please advise on how you deal with this...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#data-volumes) to isolate your volume, such container never run: they are created only (`docker create`).

That means you need to mount that data volume container into other containers for them to access that volume.
That mitigates a bit the dangerous entrypoint: a simple docker run would have access to nothing, since no `-v` mounting volume option would have been set.

Another approach is to at least have the script declared as `CMD`, not `ENTRYPOINT` (and for the `ENTRYPOINT` as `[ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]`. That way, it is easier to docker run with an alternative command (passed as parameter, overriding `CMD`), instead of having to *always* execute the script just because it is an `ENTRYPOINT`.